# the_post hook is not firing for me

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions

I have a super simple requirement here. I have added a meta field to all posts that will allow a url to be used to redirect the post (i have reasons for doing it this way). I am trying to trigger this on the action "the_post", but for some reason it doesnt seem to fire. Here is what ive added

```
function nb_checkredirect($post)
{
    if(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nb_postredirect', true ) != "") 
    {
        header('Location: '.get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nb_postredirect', true ));
        wp_die();
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'nb_checkredirect' );
```

I have checked what gets output to the PHP error log and there doesnt appear to be anything going wrong.

Comment: are you sure that `nb_checkredirect()` is not being called?  Could it be that `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nb_postredirect', true )` isn't returning what you think it should?

Comment: I modified the function so that die(); was the first line of the method and it still wasn't firing

Comment: When and how is the post_meta updated, and have you checked to be sure that it (or anything) is there when the_post action occurs? For example, if you're (successfully) adding the post_meta as part of the same process, it won't be found until the next time around.

Comment: in your template, are you calling one of [the_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/),  [setup_postdata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/)?  Because it is those functions that ultimately fire `the_post`, via [WP_Query::setup_postdata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/setup_postdata/).

Comment: i have purchased a premium theme for this so i am assuming that it calls all the proper methods that it should. I am 100% sure the meta field is set though, i can save it fine in the main editor so i know it exists for sure

Comment: Chances are good that the_post will fire after output has started, which means it's too late to set headers and redirect. template_redirect is the last reliable action that fires before template output starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your post_meta is being properly added, that the post in question is a real post, and that the value of 'nb_postredirect' is a good URL, I'd try:

```
function nb_checkredirect( $post ) {

    //don't have to use get_post_meta!*
    if ( $post->nb_postredirect ) {

        wp_redirect( $post->nb_postredirect );

        exit;

    }

}

add_action( 'the_post', 'nb_checkredirect' );
```

Tested on my own site.

*Learned this just while checking up on this question - very nice.

Comment: the other answer was also correct, but it wasnt the hook that was the problem. This worked, but it seemed that using wp_redirect was what i needed. Not sure why the built in php method of it wasnt working

Answer (score 1):

The redirect headers must be sent before the page is loaded. Please hook into template_redirect

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nb_postredirect', true ) != "" )
    {
        wp_redirect( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nb_postredirect', true ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Pls also see:

1. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php